# Cardioid: converting parametric form into polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am interested in converting parametric equations:

$$\varphi=\left(\varphi_{1},\varphi_{2}\right)=\left(2\cos{t}-\cos{2t},2\sin{t}-\sin{2t}\right)$$

which describe a cardioid, into polar coordinates. What would be a good beginning for this type of an operation? I would be thankful for some hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parametric equations describe $(x,y)(t) = (2 \cos(t) - \cos(2t), 2 \sin(t) - \sin(2t))$:

[image]

In order to convert this into polar coordinates, express the radius, and the angle in terms of $x$ and $y$ first:
$$
    r(t)^2 = x(t)^2 + y(t)^2
$$
this would be a simple expression in terms of $\cos(t)$. You could them express the polar angle using [`atan2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) as follows $\theta(t) = \arctan(x(t), y(t))$. The radial representation would be obtained if it were possible to solve for $t = t(\theta)$, and substituted into $r(t)$ to obtain $r(\theta)$. But the equation is not linear and does not admit a simple closed-form.

However, seeing that $r(t)$ is much simpler, we can invert it to find $t=t(r)$ and then $\theta(r) = \theta(t(r))$. Doing so will only allow us to parametrize half of the cardoid, due explicit symmetry $r(t) = r(2\pi - t)$.

If you permit the use of software, here is a way to get the radial representation:

[image]

Comment: Well, first of all, thank you for a thorough answer. By letting $\theta(r)=\theta(t(r))$ and solving for $r$ in terms of $\theta$ I arrive at $r=\sqrt{5-4\cos{\theta}}$. This, as you mentioned, is the parametrization of only half of the cardioid... indeed, the full polar form of cardioid generated by a circle with radius $1$ seems to be more simple ($r=2+2\cos{\theta}$). Is there any way we can obtain a full representation without using software?

Comment: The simple equation is for the shifted cardoid, that is the one parameterized as $(2\cos(t) - 1 - \cos(2t), 2 \sin(t) - \sin(2t))$. If you start with this parametrization, I am confident you can recover the simple answer you are looking for, i.e. $r = 2 - 2 \cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct...

Answer (score 1):

I was working to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/371414/8581) by very tedious manipulating relations and some substitutions in Maple that I saw this old question. I can see that we get $$(x^2+y^2-1)^2-4((x-1)^2+y^2)=0$$ The final step indeed is to use $x=r\cos\theta,~~y=r\sin\theta$.

Comment: ALso needs an UV +1\

Answer (score 0):

Hint: compute the radius and the angle as a function of $t$! ;-)

The radius is the square root of the sum of the squares of the two components; the angle can be determined using the inverse of the tangent function.

Answer (score -3):

In GeoGebra you could try something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdxaC.png

There is still a minor issue with that attempt (near the points where the graph crosses the y-axis), but with a little tweaking it should work out ok.

To elaborate a little: The rectangular form of the curve is given in terms of horizontal and vertical displacement in a parameter. If you use the Pythagorean theorem, you can obtain the displacement along a ray starting at the origin. Then you use the arctan of the ratio of vertical displacement over horizontal displacement to transform the parameter in a suitable fashion. This can sometimes result in a graph that is a mirror image of the curve that you're after, hence there is an if command that applies a transformation when the parameter is in a certain range and the chosen range of the parameter can also make a difference. By tweaking those aspects, you can obtain the desired parametric curve in polar form. With Wolfram Alpha you can find the root of 2 cos(x)-cos(2x) (the point where the graph intersects the x-axis) and this can be used to set the appropriate range.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xosZK.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMHFx.png

Comment: The question is about how to begin with parametric equations.  Your answer is to provide a screenshot from GeoGebra with no further commentary.  Can you please explain how your answer actually addresses the question?  Can you also please explain what your answer adds which has not already been covered?

Comment: The screenshot shows two equations for parametric curves. One is the parametric curve in rectangular form given in this discussion and the other is an equivalent parametric curve in polar form. The topic of this discussion seems to be that given a parametric curve in rectangular form how to obtain a polar form of the same parametric curve. One of the answers illustrates how to do it in Mathematica and I thought it was useful to provide a hint how to do it in GeoGebra. The proces to obtain it is somewhat trivial and can be more or less deduced from the answers already given.