# Parametrization of the curve $(2\cos t - \sin 2t, 2\sin t - \cos 2t)$ in polar coordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates, parametric

I'm trying to change this parametrics equations to polar coordinates

$$ X(t) = 2\cos(t) - \sin(2t)  \\ 
   Y(t) = 2\sin(t) - \cos(2t) $$

What i tryed to do was raise the two equations squared, sum  then and make some algebric manipulations.

$$ X^2 = (2\cos(t) - \sin(2t) )^2  =  4\cos^2(t) -4\cos(t)\sin(2t) + \sin^2(2t) \\
   Y^2 = (2\sin(t) - \cos(2t))^2  =  4\sin^2(t) -4\sin(t)\cos(2t) + \cos^2(2t)  \\
X^2 + Y^2 = 4(\sin(t) + \cos(t))^2 -4(\sin(t)\cos(2t) +\sin(2t)\cos(t))+(\sin(2t)+\cos(2t))^2
\\ \to X^2 + Y^2 = 5 - 4[ \sin(t)(2\cos^2(t) -1) +2\sin(t)\cos^2(t) ]
\\ \to X^2 + Y^2 = 5 - 4\sin(t)(4(\cos(t))^2 -1) 
$$

For last, we can obtain:
$$  X^2 + Y^2 = 5 - 4\sin(3t) $$

Considering that $R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2} $ and $  \theta(t) = \arctan(\frac{Y}{X}) $ ,
what i can do to replace the right hand side of the equation for polar?

**EDIT:**

Using the help of the Lord_Farin, I derivated the main equation and now i'm trying to found a relation between $\frac{X}{Y} $
and $\sin(3t) $ but i don't see a simplification in my equations. 
$$
 \frac{d}{dt} (X^2 + Y^2) = \frac{d}{dt} (5 -4\sin(3t))  \\
 2\dot{X}X + 2\dot{Y}Y = -4(3\cos(3t)) \to \\
 2\dot{X}\frac{X}{Y} + \frac{2\dot{Y}Y}{Y} = \frac{-12\cos(3t)}{Y} \to \\
 \frac{X}{Y} = \left( \frac {-12\cos(3t)}{Y} -2\dot{Y} \right).\frac{1}{2\dot{X}}
$$

where $$
  \dot{X} = -2\sin(t) -2\cos(2t) \\
  \dot{Y}=  +2\cos(t) +2\sin(2t)$$

so

$$ \frac{X}{Y} = \left( \frac {-12\cos(3t)} {2\cos(t) +2\sin(2t)} -2(2\cos(t) +2\sin(2t)) \right).\frac{1}{2(-2\sin(t) -2\cos(2t))} $$

I manipulated the values and didn't found nothing that could be replaced by $\sin(3t)$. I would be grateful if someone find a relationship.

Comment: It might be useful to derive $X^2+Y^2 = 5 - 4 \sin 3t$ using the sine addition formula. For the $\theta$, I see no nice expansion. However, for $\theta$ you need to pay attention to the signs of $X, Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may manipulate the relations $$x(t) = 2\cos(t) - \sin(2t)  \\ 
   y(t) = 2\sin(t) - \cos(2t)$$ many times to get the right answer, but plotting it by Maple:

[image]

and having the whole shape in my mind I could find the right connecting relation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltoid_curve). Note that we need a proper transformation to make the plot skew.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{{\rm X}\pars{t} = 2\cos\pars{t} - \sin\pars{2t}\,,\quad 
     {\rm Y}\pars{t} = 2\sin\pars{t} - \cos\pars{2t}}$

> $$
> {\rm Y}\pars{t} = 2\sin\pars{t} - \cos\pars{2t}
> = 2\sin\pars{t} - \bracks{1 - 2\sin^{2}\pars{t}}
> = 2\bracks{\sin\pars{t} + \half}^{2} - {3 \over 2}
> $$
> $$
> \sin\pars{t} = \pm\,{\root{2{\rm Y}\pars{t} + 3} - 1 \over 2}\tag{1}
> $$

$$
{\rm X}\pars{t} = 2\cos\pars{t} - \sin\pars{2t}
= 2\cos\pars{t} - 2\sin\pars{t}\cos\pars{t}
= 2\cos\pars{t}\bracks{1 - \sin\pars{t}}
$$
$$
\cos\pars{t} = \half\,{{\rm X}\pars{t} \over 1 - \sin\pars{t}}
\quad\mbox{and}\ \pars{~\mbox{see Eq.}\ \pars{1}~}\quad
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{rclcl}
1 - \sin\pars{t} &= & {3 - \root{2{\rm Y}\pars{t} + 3} \over 2} & \mbox{if} & +
\\
1 - \sin\pars{t} &= & {1 + \root{2{\rm Y}\pars{t} + 3} \over 2} & \mbox{if} & -
\end{array}\right.
$$
$$
\cos\pars{t}
=
\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{lcl}
{{\rm X}\pars{t} \over 3 - \root{2{\rm Y}\pars{t} + 3}} & \mbox{if} & +
\\
{{\rm X}\pars{t} \over 1 + \root{2{\rm Y}\pars{t} + 3}} & \mbox{if} & -
\\[2mm]
&&\mbox{See}\ \pars{1}\ \mbox{for the}\ \pm\ \mbox{signs meaning.}
\end{array}\right.
$$

> With $\pars{1}$ and $\pars{2}$ and the identity
> $\cos^{2}\pars{t} + \sin^{2}\pars{t} = 1$ we get:
> $$\color{#0000ff}{\large\left\lbrace%
> \begin{array}{lclcl}
> \pars{{\rm X} \over 3 - \root{2{\rm Y} + 3}}^{2}
> +
> \pars{\root{2{\rm Y} + 3} - 1 \over 2}^{2}
> & = & 1 & \mbox{if} & +
> \\[2mm]
> \pars{{\rm X} \over1 + \root{2{\rm Y} + 3}}^{2}
> +
> \pars{\root{2{\rm Y} + 3} - 1 \over 2}^{2} & = & 1 & \mbox{if} & -
> \end{array}\right.}
> $$
> See $\pars{1}$ for the $\pm$ signs meaning.

Comment: Some problems of careless signs when taking square roots notwithstanding, how does this answer the query for a parametrization **in polar coordinates**?

Comment: Signs already checked !!!

Comment: "Already checked" meaning "modified or added since last comment"?